# Flat design captcha code or name of it

Tags: javascript, html, captcha

There are styles of captcha but there is a flat design captcha

Please open [this link](http://sh.st/hOG5K)

After opening it will ask you to prove that you are not robot and there will appear a box. 
I want to know that whats is the name of that captcha or whats is the html or javascript code for it.
Please also answer with a simple code for it which i can add into my html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google reCAPTCHA V2,

Skip to Using reCAPTCHA V2 for same animation effect..

https://support.google.com/recaptcha/

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any simple code for it that can be added to html anywhere?

Comment: @AhmadTaha, did you follow the link? Google's documentation describes its usage in detail.

Comment: @AhmadTaha, please go through documentation, Google documented in an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

It's the Google recaptcha.

See here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro

Comment: This is true, but the question is about the theme -- which is indeed customizable.